# Why image generated from base64 binary data won't display?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coldfusion, upload, binaryfiles

I'm trying to grab an image from a remote location, resize it and save it to Amazon S3.

Problem is, I can save the image to S3 allright, but when I try to display it, the browser says `image can't be displayed because it contains errors`. I'm sure this is due to me doing the following:

a) Grab image from remote location:

```
  <cfhttp timeout="45" 
      throwonerror="no" 
      url="#variables.testFilePath#" 
      method="get" 
      useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12" 
      getasbinary="yes" 
      result="objGet">
```

b) Create image to validate and resize

```
<cfset objImage = ImageNew(objGet.FileContent);
```

c) After resizing, I'm converting the resized image (!) back to binary data, because the following function call to S3.cfc needs a valid file path to read the image again as binaryData. I'm doing this:

```
 <cfset variables.filekey = toBase64( objImage )>
```

instead of this:

```
 <cffile action="readBinary" file="#arguments.uploadDir##arguments.fileKey#" variable="binaryFileData">
```

because I can't get a valid `arguments.uploadDir` to work, so instead of re-reading the image here, I thought I just convert back to binary data and save this to S3.
Which converts my image back to a base64 string, which I then save at S3.

**Question:**
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I guess it's the base64 getasbinary and toBase64. But I'm not sure.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert it back to binary. Just use the `cfimage` tag to write it to disk, and then use the path to send the image off to Amazon. Then delete the image when you're done with it.

Comment: @frequent - If you ultimately need to save the image to disk anyway, why not just do that in your `cfhttp` call (as suggested in one of your another threads)?

Comment: @Leigh: I had hoped to get by without saving to "my" disk and deleting files after storing on S3. Looks like it doesn't work though :-(

Comment: @DanShort: I guess I will go with your approach right now, althgouh I was hoping this would be possible without intermim-saving to disk. I only converted back to binary, because the s3.cfc will make an additional `cffile action="readBinary"` which I wanted to avoid and which also requires a valid path, which in turn requires to save to disk, because I couldn't get it to work with a temp path. So my idea was `readbinary>newImage>resize>backtobinary>s3` vs now doing `readbinary>newImage>resize>save-to-disk>re-read-from-disk>s3>delete-from-disk`.

Comment: Did you try just sending the image object itself?

Comment: ok. I have it working, but need to interim-save-to-disk. Doesn't work without and since this is a potentially repetitive interaction, I also worry about running out of memory. Thanks for the info.